# Find average for first, second and third decade of each months for couple of years in R

Tags: r, average

I have  a dataframe (calls Metheo). One column contains dates and the next different parameters, which were measured each day for 20 years. 
I simply want to create a new dataframe that contains average for first, second and third decade of each months for all years (20 years).

But some of the months have 31 or 30 days and the Februar has 28 or 29 days. How to do it?

```
Metheo[1:20,]
         Date Tmax  Tmin Tmean Rainfall Humidity Sunshine Cloud Wind SeeLevelPressure
1  1997-01-01  4.4   1.5   2.7      0.0       80      0.0   5.8  2.6           1030.5
2  1997-01-02  5.8  -1.7   0.9      0.0       79      0.3   1.4  2.4           1030.8
3  1997-01-03  4.0  -2.5   1.1      0.0       79      0.3   3.2  4.0           1027.8
4  1997-01-04  1.9  -4.5  -3.8      0.0       83      0.4   2.2  1.9           1025.8
5  1997-01-05 -3.0  -8.3  -6.8      0.0       84      0.5   2.0  2.5           1024.7
6  1997-01-06 -4.5  -9.0  -7.2      0.0       81      0.6   0.1  2.8           1022.1
7  1997-01-07 -5.2  -9.5  -7.3      0.0       83      0.6   1.8  2.8           1019.6
8  1997-01-08  1.4  -9.4  -3.1      0.0       84      0.0   4.2  4.4           1014.4
9  1997-01-09  1.5  -4.8  -3.8      0.1       85      0.0   7.8  4.0           1022.8
10 1997-01-10 -2.5  -7.5  -6.3      0.0       91      0.0   6.0  2.3           1018.6
11 1997-01-11 -3.5  -9.2  -5.6       NA       90      0.0   5.6  2.9           1006.6
12 1997-01-12  0.5  -4.4  -1.2      0.4       95      0.0   8.0  4.6            993.5
13 1997-01-13 -2.0  -3.8  -2.8      2.8       88      0.0   7.9  5.0            990.4
14 1997-01-14 -0.7  -4.5  -2.2      8.7       88      0.0   8.0  4.8            979.1
15 1997-01-15 -0.6  -7.0  -4.7      3.9       85      0.0   7.6  3.2           1004.2
16 1997-01-16 -1.7  -7.0  -2.5      1.9       91      0.0   8.0  3.9           1002.4
17 1997-01-17 -0.5  -3.0  -2.1     15.2       94      0.0   8.0  7.4            999.2
18 1997-01-18 -2.6 -10.8  -7.9      1.2       80      0.1   4.2  6.3           1013.1
19 1997-01-19  5.8 -13.0   1.6       NA       75      0.0   7.1  9.3           1006.3
20 1997-01-20  6.2  -2.1   2.4      0.2       79      0.0   7.9  6.8            994.0

> 

4   1997-01-04  1.9  -4.5  -3.8      0.0       83      0.4   2.2  1.9           1025.8
5   1997-01-05 -3.0  -8.3  -6.8      0.0       84      0.5   2.0  2.5           1024.7
6   1997-01-06 -4.5  -9.0  -7.2      0.0       81      0.6   0.1  2.8           1022.1
7   1997-01-07 -5.2  -9.5  -7.3      0.0       83      0.6   1.8  2.8           1019.6
8   1997-01-08  1.4  -9.4  -3.1      0.0       84      0.0   4.2  4.4           1014.4
9   1997-01-09  1.5  -4.8  -3.8      0.1       85      0.0   7.8  4.0           1022.8
10  1997-01-10 -2.5  -7.5  -6.3      0.0       91      0.0   6.0  2.3           1018.6
11  1997-01-11 -3.5  -9.2  -5.6       NA       90      0.0   5.6  2.9           1006.6
12  1997-01-12  0.5  -4.4  -1.2      0.4       95      0.0   8.0  4.6            993.5
13  1997-01-13 -2.0  -3.8  -2.8      2.8       88      0.0   7.9  5.0            990.4
14  1997-01-14 -0.7  -4.5  -2.2      8.7       88      0.0   8.0  4.8            979.1
15  1997-01-15 -0.6  -7.0  -4.7      3.9       85      0.0   7.6  3.2           1004.2
16  1997-01-16 -1.7  -7.0  -2.5      1.9       91      0.0   8.0  3.9           1002.4
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Metheo)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Metheo, 30))`. And you want averages by month only or by month and by decade?

Comment: 018-08-25", "2018-08-26", "2018-08-27", "2018-08-28", "2018-08-29", 
"2018-08-30", "2018-08-31"), class = "factor"), Tmax = c(4.4, 
5.8, 4, 1.9, -3), Tmin = c(1.5, -1.7, -2.5, -4.5, -8.3), Tmean = c(2.7, 
0.9, 1.1, -3.8, -6.8), Rainfall = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Humidity = c(80L, 
79L, 79L, 83L, 84L), Sunshine = c(0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), Cloud = c(5.8, 
1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 2), Wind = c(2.6, 2.4, 4, 1.9, 2.5), SeeLevelPressure = c(1030.5, 
1030.8, 1027.8, 1025.8, 1024.7)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I´d like an average for 10-days. Like 10 first days of January and second 10 days of January and third 10 days of January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with package `dplyr`. It also uses packages `zoo`, function `as.yearmon` and `lubridate` function `day`.

```
library(dplyr)

Metheo$Date <- as.Date(Metheo$Date)

Metheo %>%
  mutate(Month = zoo::as.yearmon(Date),
         Tens = floor((lubridate::day(Date) - 1)/10)*10,
         Tens = ifelse(Tens == 30, 20, Tens),
         Month = paste(Month, Tens)) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Tmax:SeeLevelPressure), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
## A tibble: 2 x 10
#  Month  Tmax  Tmin Tmean Rainfall Humidity Sunshine Cloud  Wind
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 jan …  0.38 -5.57 -3.36     0.01     82.9     0.27  3.45  2.97
#2 jan …  0.09 -6.48 -2.5      4.29     86.5     0.01  7.23  5.42
## ... with 1 more variable: SeeLevelPressure <dbl>
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
Metheo <-
structure(list(Date = structure(1:20, .Label = c("1997-01-01", 
"1997-01-02", "1997-01-03", "1997-01-04", "1997-01-05", "1997-01-06", 
"1997-01-07", "1997-01-08", "1997-01-09", "1997-01-10", "1997-01-11", 
"1997-01-12", "1997-01-13", "1997-01-14", "1997-01-15", "1997-01-16", 
"1997-01-17", "1997-01-18", "1997-01-19", "1997-01-20"), class = "factor"), 
    Tmax = c(4.4, 5.8, 4, 1.9, -3, -4.5, -5.2, 1.4, 1.5, -2.5, 
    -3.5, 0.5, -2, -0.7, -0.6, -1.7, -0.5, -2.6, 5.8, 6.2), Tmin = c(1.5, 
    -1.7, -2.5, -4.5, -8.3, -9, -9.5, -9.4, -4.8, -7.5, -9.2, 
    -4.4, -3.8, -4.5, -7, -7, -3, -10.8, -13, -2.1), Tmean = c(2.7, 
    0.9, 1.1, -3.8, -6.8, -7.2, -7.3, -3.1, -3.8, -6.3, -5.6, 
    -1.2, -2.8, -2.2, -4.7, -2.5, -2.1, -7.9, 1.6, 2.4), Rainfall = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, NA, 0.4, 2.8, 8.7, 3.9, 1.9, 
    15.2, 1.2, NA, 0.2), Humidity = c(80L, 79L, 79L, 83L, 84L, 
    81L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 91L, 90L, 95L, 88L, 88L, 85L, 91L, 94L, 
    80L, 75L, 79L), Sunshine = c(0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 
    0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0), Cloud = c(5.8, 
    1.4, 3.2, 2.2, 2, 0.1, 1.8, 4.2, 7.8, 6, 5.6, 8, 7.9, 8, 
    7.6, 8, 8, 4.2, 7.1, 7.9), Wind = c(2.6, 2.4, 4, 1.9, 2.5, 
    2.8, 2.8, 4.4, 4, 2.3, 2.9, 4.6, 5, 4.8, 3.2, 3.9, 7.4, 6.3, 
    9.3, 6.8), SeeLevelPressure = c(1030.5, 1030.8, 1027.8, 1025.8, 
    1024.7, 1022.1, 1019.6, 1014.4, 1022.8, 1018.6, 1006.6, 993.5, 
    990.4, 979.1, 1004.2, 1002.4, 999.2, 1013.1, 1006.3, 994)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It is almos exactly what I need. But there is a little problem with the months that are 31 days. It leaves one day as an new group. What to do with this? How to corect this?

Comment: @Ewa Done. The new code puts day 31 in the 20's group.

Comment: Rui Barradas, it warks perfectly. Many thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages. But first, you need to calculate the decade:

```
Metheo %>% group_by(decade=floor(year(Date)/10)*10, month=month(Date)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Tmax, Tmin, Tmean, Rainfall, Humidity, Sunshine, Cloud, Wind, SeeLevelPressure), funs(mean))
```

*Edit* Seeing the comment about only calculating across the first 10 days of each month, we can simply add a filter:

```
Metheo %>% filter(day(Date) <= 10) %>%
  group_by(decade=floor(year(Date)/10)*10, month=month(Date)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Tmax, Tmin, Tmean, Rainfall, Humidity, Sunshine, Cloud, Wind, SeeLevelPressure), funs(mean))
```

*Sorry*, see the `decaday` for running 10 days interval. Same as decade, but what do you do about day 31? Let's throw another function:

```
df %>% group_by(decade=floor(year(Date)/10)*10, month=month(Date), decaday=cut(day(Date), breaks=c(0,10,20))) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Tmax, Tmin, Tmean, Rainfall, Humidity, Sunshine, Cloud, Wind, SeeLevelPressure), funs(mean))

  decade month decaday  Tmax  Tmin Tmean Rainfall Humidity Sunshine Cloud  Wind SeeLevelPressure
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1   1990     1 (0,10]   0.38 -5.57 -3.36     0.01     82.9     0.27  3.45  2.97            1024.
2   1990     1 (10,20]  0.09 -6.48 -2.5     NA        86.5     0.01  7.23  5.42             999.
```

Comment: Thank you. I did hw you advised(it worked) but it is not exactly what I need.
I´d like to group the date by 10 days. So I´d like to get 1.

Comment: You have to explain yourself more clearly and provide an example of your expected output.

Comment: Thank you. I did hw you advised(it worked) but it is not exactly what I need.
I´d like to group the date by 10 days. So I´d like to get: 1. 1998 1-10 day of January, 2. 1998 1-10 days of February etc. Then  1998 11-20 days of January, 1998 11-20 days of February etc. And Then 21- up to no more than 31(because there are months with 30, 28 or 29 days) so 1998 21 up to 31 January, 1998 21-28 (or29) February etc . And like this for all months and years. It is a bit tricky to explain. I hope you will understand me :)

Comment: Your initial question asked about grouping in decades, but now you are asking about years. Either way, with the answer given, you have the tools to group as you see fit. As for your comment, this is a simple ordering issue. Use `arrange` by appending it as such: `%>% arrange(decaday, year)` to achieve the ordering in your comment.

Comment: Thank You Gumble, It does not work particularly as I wish. I got results only for 1990, 2000, and 2010 and there are some NA values. Sorry for the confusion. It is not so easy to explain.

Comment: Ah, if you by "decade" meant a period of 10 days  and not 10 years, replace `decade=floor(year(Date)/10)*10` with `year=year(Date)` in the `group_by`. The 10 days (what I refer to as `decadays`) is already there.